# How to fetch field value of all documents of collection from firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named categorymovie and each category contains a list of Movie

here now i want only list of all  movies from each document's field 'movies' from all category

here is firebase design

[image]

this is my function where i want to apply logic

```
void fetchMovieOnly() async {
    List<Movie> allMovies = [];
    final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final snapshot =
        await _db.collection("MovieCategories").get();
//what code for fetching movies from querysnapshot


    
  }
```

here is my movie class

```
class Movie {
  String id;
  String name;
  Movie({required this.id, required this.name});

  toJson() {
    return {
      'Id': id,
      'Name': name,
    };
  }

  factory Movie.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map){
    return Movie(
      id: map['Id'],
      name: map['Name'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to query all the MovieCategories. Once you have the list of MovieCategories, loop or map each document and extract the Movies from each document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
Future<List<Movie>> fetchMovieOnly() async {
      List<Movie> allMovies = [];
      final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      final snapshot = await _db.collection("MovieCategories").get();
    
      snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data();
        if (data['movies'] != null) {
          data['movies'].forEach((movieData) {
            Movie movie = Movie.fromMap(movieData);
            allMovies.add(movie);
          });
        }
      });
      return allMovies;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void fetchMovieOnly() async {
    List<Movie> allMovies = [];
    final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final snapshot =
        await _db.collection("MovieCategories").get().then((value) {
      for (var doc in value.docs) {
        List<dynamic> list = doc['Movies'];

        allMovies.addAll(list.map((e) => Movie.fromMap(e)).toList());
      }
    });
  }
```